# I can't get $_POST from a dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, mysqli

One of the problems I am having is that so many people have written tutorials but have not removed them when they became out of date. For a beginner, this is extremely confusing. I've started checking the date on all tutorials now.
Sorry, that was a digression. I can get a results page that shows everything in the database but when I try to refine that by using a dropdown menu, I get a blank page. I've read everything I can find and tried the suggestions but I haven't got anywhere after four or five hours so here I am again.

This is the dropdown. It goes to the page but shows no results.

```
 <form action="search2.php" method="post">

<?php


$mysqli = new mysqli(localhost,user,password,database);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM engravers ORDER BY Country";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

?>
<select  name ="dropdown">
<?php

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=\"{$row['Country']}\">";
    echo $row['Country'];
    echo "</option>";
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" />   
        </form>
```

This makes the dropdown menu as expected but clicking submit gets no results. Here is where I'm trying to go.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli(localhost,user,password,database);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

}

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Country = $_POST['Country']");

$img_url = "http://www.engravedstamps.net/images/";  
print '<table border="1" >';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
 print '<tr>';
 print '<td>'.$row["Key"].'</td>';
 print '<td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>';
 print '<td>'.$row["Year"].'</td>';
 print '<td>'.$row["Description"].'</td>';

 print  '<td>'.'<img src="'.$img_url.$row['Images'].'" />'.'</td>'; 
 print '</tr>';
 }  
 print '</table>';


$results->free();

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown is named "dropdown" so, you can read the value with `$_POST['dropdown']`. In search2.php, you used  `$_POST['Country']`.

edit : Beware of SQL injection. As you are learning, pay attention to this. Prohibit direct variable utilization into your query in favor of prepared query.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Country = $_POST['Country']");
```

To:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Country = $_POST['dropdown']");
```

Because you have:

```
<select  name ="dropdown">
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried it both ways and have changed back now but am still getting no answer. I must have something else wrong. I have started rewriting this using prepared statements but I want to understand where this is wrong before moving on. Can you see anything else?

Answer (score -1):

You have an SQL Injection bug, filter that $_POST['dropdown'].

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Country = $_POST['Country']");
```